# How to get value of textbox using jquery which is created dynamically?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on mvc4 project.

I want to set an validation alert message if my dynamically created textbox having `null` value

for that i tried like following

```
  function ValidateForm() {
        debugger;
        $("#MYFORM tr td").find("input:text").each(function (index) {
            debugger;
            if ($(this).attr("value") == undefined && $(this).attr("value") == "") {
                alert("values are null..")
                return false;
            }

        });            
    }
```

> Please let me know the syntax for jquery to check the null value.
>
> My problem is I have more than one TEXTBOX's in my FORM

Comment: `if (!this.value)` ???  Because empty string is evaluated as false in javascript

Comment: Why do you check for undefined and empty values in the same conditional? The value is either empty or not empty.

Comment: What if I have more than one textboxes in my FORM?

Comment: @ashuthinks you are already iterating through all inputs, so you have to code your logic according to this. We don't know what exactly you are expecting to do. You should set a boolean variable flag and return this variable from validateForm() function, not from the each loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `val()`

```
    function ValidateForm() {
                var flag=0;
                debugger;
                $("#MYFORM tr td").find("input:text").each(function (index) {
                    debugger;
                    if ($(this).val() == undefined && $(this).val() == "" && $(this).val()==null) {//use val() here
                  alert("values are null..");
                 flag=1;
                //$(this).css("border","1px solid red"); all input which are null will be have red border
                  }
            });  
            if(flag==1){
                 return false;
            } 
            else{
               return true;
            }         
        }
```

Comment: I have 10 textboxes on my page which are created dynamically now my problem is those textboxes have dynamic id's when i clicked on save button i need to check them all for null

Comment: then this code will work as we are iterating all input in this form.

Comment: thanks but when i have value in 1st textbox it is saving 
i want to iterate till all textboxes then i can simply check is any textbox having any value then save that into db

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44487/discussion-between-somnath-kharat-and-ashuthinks)

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of the following methods to check if the value is empty:

```
if(!$(this).val())

if($(this).val().length == 0)
```

Comment: Your loop will handle this, although it might be better to change it to: $("#MYFORM input, #MYFORM select, #MYFORM textarea") to handle all form types.

Answer (score 1):

working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/9NMmx/2/

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#MYFORM tr td').html("<input type='text' />");
  });


$(document).on("blur", "#MYFORM input[type=text]", function () {
    ValidateForm($(this));
});

function ValidateForm(element) {
    if ($(element).val().length < 1) {
        alert("values are null..")
    }
}
```

you need to bind event on document level for dynamically created HTML elements.

Comment: how your are defining <input type='text' id='txt1' /> ? 
id'd are going to create dynamically ??

Comment: you are returning from each loop, not from function

Comment: i just mentioned id for testing purposes..you can see my answer, you bind event of all textbox insife your form using this #MYFORM tr td input

Comment: actually dont need $.each for this.. see my updated fiddle and answer

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` condition will never be true. Change it from:

```
if ($(this).attr("value") == undefined && $(this).attr("value") == "")
```

To:

```
if ($(this).attr("value") == undefined || $(this).attr("value") == "")
```

OR:

```
if ($(this).val() == undefined || $(this).val() == "")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to jQuery.

In Javascript, one concept is undefined (value does not exist), other null and other empty string ''.

I suggest first checking for undefined and null, and then check for empty string
Also I suggest cache the return value.

```
var val = $(this).val();
if(val == null || val.length == 0)
    alert('values are null ...');
```

val == null is evaluated to true whether val is undefined or null.